# rstudio-server on Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I run locally a service, `rstudio-server`. This service can be accessed on my machine local IP, port 8787.

Now, I would like to access this service from my server with this address: rstudio.example.com (a A entry has be done).

I use *Nginx* and created this block:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name rstudio.example.com;
    root /usr/lib64/rstudio-server/www;
    include /etc/nginx/ssl/rstudio.ssl.conf;


location / {
    # rewrite ^/rstudio/(.*)$ /$1 break;
    #proxy_pass http://192.168.1.94:8787;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/run/rstudio-server/rstudio-server.sock;
    #proxy_redirect http://192.168.1.94:8787/ rstudio.myexample.com;
    proxy_redirect http://unix:/run/rstudio-server/rstudio-server.sock rstudio.myexample.com;
    #proxy_http_version 1.1;
    #proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    #proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade"; 
    }
```

I voluntary let commented all options I have tried. None of all kinds of solutions let me connect to the service on example.com.
All I can see on my log is:

```
*5 epoll_wait() reported that client prematurely closed connection, so upstream connection is closed too while sending request to upstream
```

Googling this error did not allow me to find a clear answer.

What do I wrong in my proxy setup on Nginx? 
Thank you for hints.

Comment: Just to clarify the situation: you have a machine which is running a web service on port 8787, and you're trying to run an nginx server on the same machine to proxy to it, or are these two distinct hosts? What does your network look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
http {

  map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
      default upgrade;
      ''      close;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name rstudio.example.com;
    root /usr/lib64/rstudio-server/www;
    include /etc/nginx/ssl/rstudio.ssl.conf;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://192.168.1.94:8787;
      proxy_redirect http://192.168.1.94:8787/ $scheme://$host/;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
      proxy_read_timeout 20d;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: working. Weirdly, I already tested this configuration and didn't work. I suppose I used the unix socket and not the http.